# Set value of option button to true based on value of cell

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I have an Excel sheet "TestSheet", and a user form frmTestForm, with an option button named OptionButton1.  I added the button manually from the editor, so I believe it is a Form Controls option button. I want to turn on (meaning show as selected) the option button based on the value of cell C2 in sheet "TestSheet".

```
        Sub Test_Form()
            Worksheets("TestSheet").Activate
            Dim OptionButton1 As OptionButton
            Dim myopt As OptionButton

            Set myopt = OptionButton1

            With frmTest_Form
                If Range("C2").Value = 5 Then
                    OptionButton1.Value = True   'Errors here
                End If
            End With
       frmTest_Form.Show
       End Sub
```

The error message is "Object variable or With lock not set", which I believe indicates the option button is not properly defined, but I don't know how to fix it.  Thanks in advance for your help.

I have edited the code to reflect both comments. I still have the sane error message, "Object variable or With lock not set" in the line OptionButton1.Value = True.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Objects need `Set` in front of them  to assign its value, also you have `frmTest_Form` and `frmTestForm` which is it?

Comment: For declaration of control, you must asign it with new or set with the current control, for example dim myopt as optionbutton: set myopt=optionbutton1

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!  Changed code as follows:

```
        Sub Test_Form()
             Dim OptionButton1 As Variant

             Set OptionButton1 = frmTest_Form.OptionButton1
             If Range("C2").Value = 5 Then
                 OptionButton1.Value = True
             End If

             frmTest_Form.Show
        End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!